# Action Bar Sherlock with buttons

Tags: android, tabs, action, actionbarsherlock

i'm building an app and i really want to align buttons to the left using ABS (action bar sherlock) 4.0 
I really like the dropbox interface as shown under this:

[image: Dropbox interface]

So, my question is: How can i align the buttons to the left and how can i jump between views in ViewFlow using buttons?

I've seen that people can add tabs to their ABS, but not with the title like the Dropbox interface.

Thanks.
Also if u need my sourcecode i will add it later if needed.

Regards

Stian Instebø

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but I suggest switching from ViewFlow to ViewPager (built into Android). It's more compatible and easier to integrate with the Action Bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[setCustomView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) is the magic method you might be looking for.

To achieve the same layout shown in the Dropbox app, you would first call [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29) on your ActionBar.

Next, you could define the layout for the buttons somewhere in XML. Once this is done, calling setCustomView(R.layout.my_actionbar_nav) will do the trick. (It will now be positioned on the left-hand side of the ActionBar).

It'll be your responsibility to wire up the appropriate onClick listeners for your layout's inner button Views, but it's not a bad price to pay for setting up custom navigation.